# Why do the rating stars start on a new line?

Tags: jquery, html, css, rateyo

I have implemented rateYo's rating plug-in, which I really like. I am confounded by why the stars insist on breaking into a new line. My [test-site](http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/#/enablers) illustrates the problem.

I tried styling the  div with `display: inline` and `inline-block` as well as `whitespace: nowrap` to no avail. I also tried styling the label with `display: inline`. There isn't an option for the plugin relating to this issue.  What am I missing?

```
<label for="min-rating" >Minimum Rating:</label>
<div id="min-rating"></div>
```

If you elect to downvote this question, please include a reason so I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `div`s have `display: block` which makes it start on a new line. If you add this to your CSS it will work:

```
#min-rating {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I did try that, but the stars still stubbornly break onto a new line.

Comment: @rontornambe I don't know what's causing it then, sorry. When I use Chrome DevTools to make the change it works: http://i.imgur.com/kzrHPKK.png

Comment: Thanks. Another clue to investigate.

Comment: I found some CSS from another rating plugin I tried that was interfering with the rateYo plugin. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to insert it in a table

```
<table cellspacing=10>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="min-rating" >Minimum Rating:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="min-rating">****</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Note: I added a few little stars* (****) *for demonstration. you may remove it if you wish*

Comment: Thanks Ronnie, but I found the problem. See the accepted answer.